# Magento Error when trying to click on product in admin

Tags: magento, admin, product

Hi i have this error when i try to click on a product in admin

```
2016-08-29T10:37:38+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Productslider/Model/Source/Feature.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/blueb/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-08-29T10:37:38+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Productslider/Model/Source/Feature.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/blueb/public_html/app/code/local:/home/blueb/public_html/app/code/community:/home/blueb/public_html/app/code/core:/home/blueb/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/php')  in /home/blueb/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

I think i had make no changes. I dont installed a new extension. Yesterday i have edit products with no error and today the error is there

thanks for some help

Comment: do you have any product slider extension ? can you disable and check once ?

Comment: no i dont have a product slider

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?